# Hash algorithm issue with converting code from javascript to python

Tags: javascript, python

To get same hash function in javascript and python I tried to convert my javaScript function to python and completely stack with gooooogle int as result in python variant.

**javascript**

```
function str_hash(var s) {
  var hash = 0, i, chr;
  if (s.length === 0) return hash;
  for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
  {
    chr   = s.charCodeAt(i);
    hash  = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
    hash |= 0;
  }
  return hash;
};
```

output is like: -34998534 whatever

**my python try:**

```
def get_hash(s):

    h = 0

    if not s:
        return h
    
    for i in range(0, len(s)):

        h = ((h << 5) - h) + i
        h |= 0

    return h

print(get_hash('PUT LONG STRING HERE'))
```

output is like: 349832894283058945028049523548405975892375489743847490218348927483984793048218934148973940218340298489273942374902938490238482942930729487210948239407329403082738940214 whatever

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: What does the javascript line ` hash |= 0;` do?

Comment: Where in the Python code is the equivalent of javascript `chr   = s.charCodeAt(i);`?

Comment: The Python code in your question prints `746433920910091424484602890`, doesn't it?

Comment: say we use

 "hfday8ru9283y7ru-0iwr78a934-iwae9fiy7ahfday8ru9283y7ru-0iwr78a934-iwae9fiy7pkfl9iy84ewruo0wo0wo0wo0wo0wgfiy8geruo0i68ew74o-0t78-0wer8y74f0klrhesyupf0lw3kr7yuwkiy3gr0wer8y74f0klrhesyupf0lw3kr7yuwkiy3gr0wer8y74f0klrhesyupf0lw3kr7yuwkiy3grgor03984o0aerygfuiowpkfl9iy84ewruo0wo0wo0wo0wo0wgfiy8geruo0i68ew74o-0t78-0wer8y74f0klrhesyupf0lw3kr7yuwkiy3gr"

as test string

javascript and python shud have exact the same hash!

Comment: If we use `"abc"` as a test string, then both the javascript and the python hash function versions should return the same hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the python equivalent code

```
def str_hash(s):
    hash = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        chr = ord(s[i])
        hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr
        hash = hash & 0xFFFFFFFF
    return hash
```

print(str_hash("PUT LONG STRING HERE"))

the << operator in javascript is called the bitwise left shift operator. and the native code  for this is explained in the below example

```
let num = 4
let shiftBy = 2
print(num * 2 ** shiftBy)  // num * Math.pow(2,shiftBy)
print(num << shiftBy)
```

Comment: Is Python `hash = hash & 0xFFFFFFFF` the same as javascript `hash |= 0;`? Why `0xFFFFFFFF` and not `0xFFFF` ?

Comment: Oh, wow it works finally the same way like javascript one!

Comment: Big thnx, man!!!